# Exams Package - Setting up a quiz for moodle with multiple exercises

Tags: dynamic, moodle, r-exams

I am trying to set up a simple exercise for moodle with the aid of the exams package. It seems that I miss something and the file that I import to Moodle does not include all the items that are supposed to be included. The code appears below. I would appreciate any hint that could help me resolve this problem. The code is as follows:

```
    <<echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
    id     <- seq(1:220)
    age    <- round(runif(220, 18, 60), 2)
    weight <- round(runif(220, 45,100), 2)
    gender <- sample(c("male", "female"), 220, replace=T)
    mydata <- data.frame(cbind(id, gender, age, weight))
    mydata$id     <- as.numeric(mydata$id)
    mydata$age    <- as.numeric(mydata$age)
    mydata$weight <- as.numeric(mydata$weight)
    write.csv(mydata, "DataQuiz1.csv", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
    @    

    \begin{question}
    Using the data provided in \url{DataQuiz1.csv} 
    \begin{answerlist}
    \item Report the variance of participants' \texttt{weight} (rounded up to two decimal places).
    \item Report what is the \texttt{age} of the youngest person (rounded up to two decimal places).
    \item Report wht is the \texttt{age} of the eldest participant (rounded up to two decimal places).
    \item Indicate what is the 3rd quartile for the variable \texttt{weigh}  (rounded up to two places).
    \item Write down how many participants are included in the \texttt{DataQuiz1}.
    \end{answerlist}
    \end{question}

    \begin{solution}
    <<echo=FALSE, results=hide, fig=TRUE>>=
    varsol  <- var(mydata$weight)
    minsol  <- min(mydata$age)
    maxsol  <- max(mydata$age)
    sol1   <-  print (summary(mydata)[5, 4 ])
    sol2  <- nrow(mydata)
    solutions <- c(varsol, minsol, maxsol, sol1, sol2)
    answerlist(ifelse(solutions, "True", "False"))
    @ 


   To replicate the analysis in R:
    \begin{verbatim}
    ## data
    mydata <- read.csv("DataQuiz1.csv")
    ## To find the variance for weight:
    var(mydata$weight)
    ## To find the minimum value for age:
    min(mydata$age)
    ## To find the maximum value for age:
    max(mydata$age)
    ## To find what is the 3rd Quartile of weight 
    summary(mydata$weight) (and check the fifth row, fourth column)
    ## To find out how many participants
    nrow(mydata)
    \end{verbatim}

    \end{solution}

    %% \exname{find_the_variance_and_minimum}
    %% \extype{num}
    %% \exsolution{\Sexpr{fmt(c=(varsol | minsol | maxsol | sol1 | sol2), 2)}}
    %% \exclozetype{num|num|num|num|num}
    %% \extol{0.01}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three issues with the exercise that prevent it from working correctly:

1. Computing the 3rd quartile with `print (summary(mydata)[5, 4 ])` yields a character and not a numeric output. Subsequent formatting etc. as a number does thus not work. Instead use `summary(mydata$weight)[5]` or `quantile(mydata$weight, 0.75)`.
2. The `extype` needs to be `cloze` not `num`.
3. The command `fmt(c=(varsol | minsol | maxsol | sol1 | sol2), 2)` does not do what you want to do. Use `paste(fmt(solutions, 2), collapse = "|")` instead. (Note that it is important to have fixed issue 1 above for that.)

With some further streamlining the exercise then looks like this:

```
<<echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
id     <- seq(1:220)
age    <- round(runif(220, 18, 60), 2)
weight <- round(runif(220, 45,100), 2)
gender <- sample(c("male", "female"), 220, replace=TRUE)
mydata <- data.frame(cbind(id, gender, age, weight))
mydata$id     <- as.numeric(mydata$id)
mydata$age    <- as.numeric(mydata$age)
mydata$weight <- as.numeric(mydata$weight)
write.csv(mydata, "DataQuiz1.csv", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
@    

<<echo=FALSE, results=hide, fig=TRUE>>=
varsol  <- var(mydata$weight)
minsol  <- min(mydata$age)
maxsol  <- max(mydata$age)
sol1   <-  summary(mydata$weight)[5]
sol2  <- nrow(mydata)
solutions <- c(varsol, minsol, maxsol, sol1, sol2)
@ 

\begin{question}
Using the data provided in \url{DataQuiz1.csv} 
\begin{answerlist}
\item Report the variance of participants' \texttt{weight} (rounded up to two decimal places).
\item Report what is the \texttt{age} of the youngest person (rounded up to two decimal places).
\item Report wht is the \texttt{age} of the eldest participant (rounded up to two decimal places).
\item Indicate what is the 3rd quartile for the variable \texttt{weigh}  (rounded up to two places).
\item Write down how many participants are included in the \texttt{DataQuiz1}.
\end{answerlist}
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
Replicate the analysis in R:
\begin{verbatim}
## data
mydata <- read.csv("DataQuiz1.csv")
## To find the variance for weight:
var(mydata$weight)
## To find the minimum value for age:
min(mydata$age)
## To find the maximum value for age:
max(mydata$age)
## To find what is the 3rd Quartile of weight 
summary(mydata$weight)
## To find out how many participants
nrow(mydata)
\end{verbatim}
\end{solution}

%% \exname{find_the_variance_and_minimum}
%% \extype{cloze}
%% \exsolution{\Sexpr{paste(fmt(solutions, 2), collapse = "|")}}
%% \exclozetype{num|num|num|num|num}
%% \extol{0.01}
```

Comment: It worked, perfectly! Thanks a lot for your precious help, Achim!!!
And congrats on creating that invaluable package and all the supporting video material you have prepared for novice users like me.

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it's useful. Please accept my answer by clicking the check mark below the vote count on the left. Then the question is flagged as resolved here on StackOverflow. Thanks!

Comment: Dear Achim,
Again, thanks for your kind response and assistance. In the first place, I tried to upvote your answer but the system prevented me from doing so because I lack the necessary reputation (15 points or more). But thanks to you, I have just noticed that there is also the option to mark the answer as accepted. I am sorry for not having done it before. At any rate, thanks a lot.
Athanasios Mouratidis